# Htaccess: Empty $_GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

Currently I'm having a PHP page, and with htaccess I'm changing the page URL. This is my Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^customer/edit/(.*)/deletefrom/(.*)/ index.php?page=customer&edit=$1&deletefrom&=$2 [QSA,L]
```

When I'm trying to get the value from `$_GET['deletefrom']` I'm getting an empty value. But `$_GET['edit']` is working and gives an value, so that's strange. I hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^customer/edit/(.*)/deletefrom/(.*)/ index.php?page=customer&edit=$1&deletefrom&=$2 [QSA,L]
```

`&` used as separator in GET parameter, after `deletefrom` it founds `&` so you are getting empty value. Instead of above code use following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^customer/edit/(.*)/deletefrom/(.*)/ index.php?page=customer&edit=$1&deletefrom=$2& [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Wow, I feel really stupid right now. Have been looking for an hour on the internet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `&` right after `deletefrom` variable.